What's the current status of the United States by the end of Kabaneri of the Iron Fortress: Battle of Unato Castle?
Since the Kabane outbreak started in Western Europe and spread across the world, what’s the current status of the United States as of the end of the series?
The U.S. is an industrialized potential superpower that spans across an entire continent and based on the level of industrialization see in Japan, I think it’s fair to say that the global outbreak occurred roughly post-Civil War. The U.S. military (or at least the Army) would have significant combat experience, albeit against evil slave-owning traitors and not armored zombies. The U.S. also has significant rail infrastructure spanning across the continent to help with logistics . Major terrain features like the Mississippi River and Rocky Mountains would give the U.S. an edge up in fighting the Kabane because they're natural terrain obstacles which act as a force multiplier.
However on the other hand, the U.S. received significant immigrants on the East Coast which definitely had to have had a few infected. If those infected made it to New York, then it would only be a matter of time before the East Coast was taken out. It doesn’t help that the US is probably still reeling from the aftermath of the Civil War and with the Kabane running rampant, it could give cause for Neo-Confederates to rearm and take up the mantle of Confederate independence.
